# Search multiple directories and output file names

Tags: files, find, directory, ls, search

I have a list of 7 directories. Every day they get a file. I would run one command that would check all the directories at once which provides the output of the file names.

Normally I run `ls /direct1` to each of the 7 directly and honestly I tried piping all those command together but that doesn’t work either. I really don’t mind trying to figure things out on my own but I am just not sure what to search for. Most of my google results have point to scripts that would include the file names but that really seems like overkill. Maybe that's the only way and the reason for those results.

Comment: Changed comment to: Pardon my ignorance. I see what you mean. That will help after our migration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ls accepts more than one file/directory argument: try `ls /directory1 /directory2 ... /directoryN`

Edit: Also, executing several commands with independent targets after another doesn't work with pipes, but does with semicolons: `ls /directory1; ls /directory2; ...`.

Comment: WOW. Even easier than I was trying to make it. It seems like I should have known that as I use 'mv' to move multiple files. I dont pipe those....anyway, thanks!! have a wonderful day.

Answer (score 0):

If all those 7 Directory are in the one place then please refer the comment by Christopher

`ls -R`

This will list all the content of the 7 directory if they are in the same location.

Comment: oh, that is why that was suggested. I think after our migration that would apply. Thanks for that suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You can define an alias in your `~/.bashrc` file:

`nano ~/.bashrc`

Copy and paste the alias at the end of the file

`alias lsall='ls "/dir1/" "/dir2/" "/dir3/"'`

Restart your terminal and type

`lsall`